# Get columns from SQL query by various filter combinations in Java

Tags: java, sql, get, prepared-statement

I would like to write an SQL query to get all requested column combinations by the user. For example for the table user: (id, name, age, height, weight)

It should be possible to filter by the parameters [id, name], [id, name, age], [age, height], ...

Writing an SQL query for all combinations is of course too inefficient. Is there an efficient way to write an SQL query using PreparedStatement?

Something akin to this:

```
 public User getByFiltered(User userDTO){

    String sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE id=? AND age=? AND height=?";
    PreparedStatement statement = dbConnectionManager.getConnection().prepareStatement(sql);
    ...
 }
```

But basically any combination of the columns can be requested.

Comment: Make it easy to help you: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
SELECT u.*
FROM user u
WHERE (id = ? OR ? IS NULL) AND
      (age = ? OR ? IS NULL) AND
      (height = ? OR ? IS NULL);
```

Note that this requires doubling up on the parameters.

Named parameters simplify this:

```
SELECT u.*
FROM user u
WHERE (id = :id OR :id IS NULL) AND
      (age = :age OR :age IS NULL) AND
      (height = :height OR :height IS NULL);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with this:

```
SELECT * FROM user 
WHERE 
  (0 = ? OR id = ?) 
  AND 
  (0 = ? OR age = ?) 
  AND 
  (0 = ? OR height = ?)
```

When you want to search say for `age = 21` and `height = 175` (I prefer cm) and you don't care about id, you pass these parameters:

```
  (0 = 0 OR id = 0) 
  AND 
  (0 = 1 OR age = 21) 
  AND 
  (0 = 1 OR height = 175)
```

meaning the parameter for `0 = ?` will be `0` if that column is irrelevant and `1` if it is relevant (also the parameter for `id` can be anything). 
Now because `(0 = 0 OR id = 0)` evaluates always to TRUE (because `0 = 0` is `TRUE`), it does not do any filtering. 
 But because `0 = 1` is `FALSE` the other conditions: `age = 21` and `height = 175` must be `TRUE`.
This way you have 3 + 3 parameters: 
 
The first 3 are the parameters indicating if a column is: 
**relevant** (so you pass `1`)
 
or **not relevant** (so you pass `0`).
The other 3 are the actual parameters that do the filtering (or anything if that column is irrelevant).

Answer (score 0):

It is better to fetch all the records from DB without any filter and then apply the logic at Java level